# Android AnimationDrawable maximum PNG files?

Tags: android, animation, drawable

So I have about 50 PNG files that will play as my splash animation. The file names are sequenced properly and I can do like the first 10 files, anything beyond that the application force closes.

Is there a maximum number of PNG files to do an animation? Or should I just bite the bullet and create a movie file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used 640x480 png files. The most I could use before it force closed is 15.

good luck

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/wrong_xxx" android:oneshot="true">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ad_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ae_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_af_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ag_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ah_x" android:duration="100" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ai_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_aj_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ak_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_al_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_am_x" android:duration="100" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_an_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ao_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ap_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_aq_x" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wrong_ar_x" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```